# $.getJson from X files by a LOOP and STORE each in a VARIABLE using JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I need to `$.getJSON` from files by using a loop on Javascript:

```
///////JS.serial =[156,256] but i can have more than 2 values//
var Electricity = {
    refreshJson : function() {

        for(var i=0; i<JS.nbre_serials;i++)
        url = 'json/kw/kw_'+JS.serials[i]+'.json';

         $.getJSON(url, function(data){
        // ???
            Electricity.processConsumption(data_156,data_256);
        });

    },
```

I would like store each object return in a variable (i.e. `var datas_156` ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$.when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/), so you can call `Electricity.processConsumption` when all the results are ready. That is possible because `$.getJSON` returns a promise compatible object.

```
refreshJson : function() {

  var promises = [];
  for(var i=0; i<JS.nbre_serials;i++){
    var url = 'json/kw/kw_'+JS.serials[i]+'.json';
    promises.push($.getJSON(url));
  }

  $.when.apply($, promises)
    .done(function(data_156, data_256){
      Electricity.processConsumption(data_156,data_256);
    })
    .fail(function() {
      //handle errors
    });

}
```

In the example `$.when.apply($, promises)` is called that way because `$.when` won't accept an array of promises, but a variable number of parameters.
The same way you could call `Electricity.processConsumption`, so you don't have to change the code every time a new "serial" is added.

```
refreshJson : function() {

  var promises = [];
  for(var i=0; i<JS.nbre_serials;i++){
    var url = 'json/kw/kw_'+JS.serials[i]+'.json';
    promises.push($.getJSON(url));
  }

  $.when.apply($, promises)
    .done(function(){
      Electricity.processConsumption.apply(Electricity,arguments);
    })
    .fail(function() {
      //handle errors
    });

}
```

And your `processConsumption` function might be something like:

```
//somewhere in the Electricity class
processConsumption: function(){
  var data_156 = arguments[0];
  var data_256 = arguments[1];
  //do stuff
}
```

Comment: @llaid I don't understand what is the `processJsonKw` function, but I guess you mean `processConsumption`. In that case see my edit

Comment: yes Matis i changed it  that's work perfectly!  Awesome

Comment: Hello @Matias, do you have a way to ignore if a file doesn't exist without fail?